# VBA find a cell based on the value and start for loop from this cell

Tags: vba, loops, find, cell

I need to find a cell in row 3 that contains words "Start here". Then I need to make this cell a boundary of my for loop. Do you have any idea what is the right way to do it? Thank you in advance!

```
Sub sort()
Dim selectedCell As Range

'find and select cell  

Rows("3:3").Select
Set selectedCell = Selection.Find(What:="Start Here", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

 'make the cell a beginning boundary of loop 

 Count=10000
 While Not IsEmpty(Range(Cells(selectedCell), Cells(3, Count)))

   
End Sub
```

Comment: No need to select, just define the range in the find like `Set selectedCell = Worksheets(1).Rows(3).Find("Start Here", LookIn:=xlValues)` (or however you want to configure your search)

Comment: For the second part, your variable is the range. Exactly how you want to use it as a "boundary" would depend on what your loop is I guess.